# Word for houshold activities

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any generic word describing household activities such as doing dishes and mopping floors? I feel the word *chore* implies a burden and am looking for something more natural.

Comment: Don't be so down on ***chore***.  I use this all the time to describe housework, and I mean no connotation of burden.

Comment: Hm, well perhaps not a connotation of burden, but certainly something expected or assigned. Housework is better though as i am looking for something nice and casual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about just - "Housework"  ?

Comment: Pretty good actually. Could also apply to things as going grocery shopping etc couldn't it?

Comment: I would prefer the term ***errands*** for things that you need to do outside the home.

Comment: +1 for housework, but @DavidW I wouldn't say it applied to activities done outside the home, such as grocery shopping. Those might better be called 'errands' or similar

Comment: Still, good enough for my current purpose. Thanks.

Comment: At least in BE housework implies stuff you do inside the house.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously?  Since when are doing dishes and mopping floors not a burden or chore?  Might this be an exercise in denial?   Housework, I agree, is a fine word.  There's also job or task.  But to find a word that's nice and casual is almost insulting to the doer, unless you're making an "activities" chart for yourself.  I'm so curious.

Comment: Tell it like it is! If such activities weren't chores, they'd be fun. And *househusband* would be more common than [housewife](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=househusband%2Chousewife&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)